# Extracting filedescriptors from fd_set

Tags: linux, sockets, posix

I have to implement a conversion tool between two different protocols.
It should be a relatively simply loop, triggered by filedescriptor events.
The protocol APIs however:

1. st API: Is meant for use with **select()**, it expose a GetFD() method that will throw it fd's into the given fd_set using FD_SET
2. nd API: Only works with **poll()**  (it is ZMQ)

Is there any way to extract the fds from a fd_set, without calling select()? (Preferably portable)

I have tried looking into the source of the fd_set structure, but it is not really readable and probably a hint that you should not touch it through anything than the 4 macro, FD_CLR/SET/ISSET/ZERO.

```
//Pseudo-code of what i hope to achieve
// Get fd's from API1
fd_set readfds;
FD_ZERO( & readfds );
int max = api1.GetFd(readfds);
    
struct zmq_pollitem_t poll_items[MAX_COUNT];
int fd_count = 0;
convert_fdset_to_pollitem( readfds , poll_items , fd_count ); //what i need

poll_items[fd_count].fd = api2.GetFD();
poll_items[fd_count].socket = api2.GetSocket();
fd_count++;    

const uint32_t timeout_msec = 500;
int ret = zmq_poll( poll_items , fd_count , timeout_msec);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of a select() function. You can compare the return then with  each of your different protocol sockets - e.g. `if (select_socket(s1,s2) == protocol_1_sd)`. I am using that function, to handle http and https sockets.

```
// selecting corresponding socket from FD_SET
int select_socket(int sock_1, int sock_2) {

     fd_set read;
     struct timeval timeout;

     int ret = -1; 

     FD_ZERO(&read);
     FD_SET(sock_1, &read);
     FD_SET(sock_2, &read);
      
     timeout.tv_sec= 10;
     timeout.tv_usec = 0;

     if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &read, NULL, NULL, &timeout ) < 0)
         perror("select");

     for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++) {

         if (FD_ISSET(i, &read)) {

         if (i == sock_1)
            ret = sock_1; 
        
         else if (i == sock_2)
            ret = sock_2;
        
         else {
            FD_CLR(i, &read);
            ret = -1;
         }  
       }
    }

return ret;
}
```

Comment: My problem is not to find the fd origin, but to avoid having to call both select() and poll(). I have tried to update my answer to address this.

Comment: I doubt that there is a relatively simple loop solution then. Maybe you could check out  https://libevent.org/ , that might help.